# Accessing Object in an array with Blaze using Spacebars in a Meteor application

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I am trying to iterate in my template a list of objects included in an array field of a Mongo DB document using the Meteor platform.

So for example I create a MongoDB Posts collection of documents with the following JSON structure:

```
 _id: "xyxyxyxy",
 title: "my first post",
 description: "a very intresting post",
 comments:[
           {comment:"a very cool post"},{createdBy: Meteor.userId()},
           {comment:"I don't like this post"},{createdBy: Meteor.userId()}
          ]
```

Every logged-in user can add a comment that will be listed under the title and the description of a single post detail view.

So I set my template helper in my js file and added {{#each}} spacebars helper in my HTML file.

When I try to iterate the post document I get the title, the description but cannot get the values of my nested objects (comments). Instead, I get the following expression: "Object object".

How can I access those values so that I can show the comments related to the post and the user who added the comment? Thanks

Please note: I am not using aldeed simple-schema and not using pub/sub pattern. As of now I am intrested in understanding the templating part of the framework.

Comment: you should also change your inner object structure, that's doesn't make sense to have on separated object comment and createdBy, look at my answer to get the good structure

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have two {{#each}}, one to iterate over the Posts and then one inside that to iterate over comments because they are in an array structure, using the below you shouldn't need to change or define any new template helpers:

```
{{#each posts}}
  {{title}}
  {{description}}
  {{#each comments}}
    {{createdBy}}
    {{comment}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's normal, I don't know why you've wrapped your inner object comment into array, you should have this structure:

```
_id: "xyxyxyxy",
 title: "my first post",
 description: "a very intresting post",
 comments:[
           {comment:"a very cool post",createdBy: Meteor.userId()},
           {comment:"I don't like this post",createdBy: Meteor.userId()}
 ]
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. You are right. I did a mistake when writing the question. But the issue is still there. I cannot iterate and get those values. How would you set the javascript template helper and html template using spacebars?

Comment: Show me your template and related js. Don't forgot to change the structure.

Answer (score 0):

similar case using meteor-blaze where I have users database with structure like below:

```
"_id": "abcdefojsdoijfodsjoijfe",
"username": "testuser",
"emails" : [ 
           { "address": "testuser@test.com",
             "verified": "false"} 
]
```

The nested each solution like provided by Philip Pryde above will work perfectly as the calling for database such as  emails.address won't work.

So if I want to display username and email address, 
need to do like below

```
{{#each usernames}}
<p>your username: {{username}}</p>
{{#each emails}}
<p>your email: {{address}}</p>
{{/each}}
{{/each}}
```